# Visual Studio Excel Pivot Table not showing data

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, pivot-table

I am writing an application to add a pivot table sheet in an existing excel workbook. Here's the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        if (e.Name.StartsWith("~$"))
            return;

        Excel.Application oApp;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Workbook oBook;


        oApp = new Excel.Application();
        try
        {
            oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Open(e.FullPath);
            oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Excel.Range finalCell = oSheet.Cells[2, oSheet.Rows.Count];
            Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "M9");

            if (oApp.Application.Sheets.Count < 2)
            {
                oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.Add();
            }
            else
            {
                oSheet = oApp.Worksheets[2];
            }
            oSheet.Name = "Pivot Table";
            // specify first cell for pivot table
            Excel.Range oRange2 = oSheet.Cells[3,1];

            // create Pivot Cache and Pivot Table
            Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)oBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);
            Excel.PivotTable oPivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)oSheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: oPivotCache, TableDestination: oRange2, TableName: "Summary");


            Excel.PivotField oPivotField1 = (Excel.PivotField)oPivotTable.PivotFields("Field1");
            oPivotField1.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            oPivotField1.Position = 1;
            oPivotField1.Name = "Field1";

            Excel.PivotField oPivotField2 = (Excel.PivotField)oPivotTable.PivotFields("Field2");
            oPivotField2.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            oPivotField2.Position = 2;
            oPivotField2.Name = "Field2";

            oBook.Save();
            Console.WriteLine("Operation Complete");
}
```

This is inside a FileSystemWatcher's event handler for file creation. The program runs and creates the sheet for the Pivot table, but data values are not listed and also i get two separate columns. [Here's the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SUP.png)

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong. Using Visual Studio 2015 and project type is Windows Form Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the pivot cache/table creation lines:

```
Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)oBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);
Excel.PivotTable oPivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)oSheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: oPivotCache, TableDestination: oRange2, TableName: "Summary");
```

with

```
PivotCache oPivotCache = oBook.PivotCaches().Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange, XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14);
PivotTable oPivotTable = oPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination: oRange2, TableName: "Summary");
```

Note that you are doing a lot of redundant casting. You generally don't have to cast all those pivotCache and pivotfield variables.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not clear. I find using the List.Add method to be unnecessary, and instead use object-specific methods to get the best results. Also, Pivot tables/caches and their various creation syntax have always been a bit of a weak point for me, so i just use the proven methods which work.

Comment: Just an aside: if you want to do away with the Excel default Pivottable layout and use tabular form(which shows the field rows you can add this line at the end of pivottable creation: oPivotTable.RowAxisLayout(XlLayoutRowType.xlTabularRow);

Comment: Cool!! but for my requirement, i'll need the default layout!! this will help me some other time... thanks!!